# Where can I find some people to improve my speaking skills?

Tags: conversation

I am a new international student at UC Davis, and as the universities are closed at the moment I like to know some places that I can find some people to do more communication and improve my speaking skill. Maybe somewhere to do volunteer works, meeting/discussion groups, etc.

Please let me know either if there is such places in Davis, California or you have better idea for speaking skill improvement?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend talking to and studying together with your fellow students. Have digital meetings if that is what it takes. This is an excellent way of learning the content, teaches you the academic language you need, and helps to connect you with the other students in your study programme (whatever it is called over there). Probably some of them would enjoy such meetings, too.